# Lenovo ThinkPad E15 (AMD R7, Radeon) - Battery Problem

Tags: lenovo, battery, thinkpad, ubuntu-mate

I've bought a brand new ThinkPad E15 a few days ago and unfortunately have to find that the battery is constantly empty. It even discharges when the notebook is in sleep mode. This morning, for example, I fully charged it and when I got home from work tonight, it was empty again. But nobody used that thing all day.

If I had Windows, I could now do a firmware update on the Lenovo side. But how do you do that on Linux? I'm still brand new to the Linux world and would therefore be happy if someone could help me. Before ist used MacOS for many years and there's no way for me to turn back to Windows again.

So the question is, do I have to return the notebook because it is no good, or do I simply lack the right know-how to set it up properly under Linux? I've installed the lates version of Ubuntu (Mate) - 20.04.LTS...

I would be very happy to receive quick help and/or further advice.

Best regards, Mic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increase battery life on Ubuntu 20.04 and what power saving software should I install, if any?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1309396/how-to-increase-battery-life-on-ubuntu-20-04-and-what-power-saving-software-shou)

Comment: Run `fwupdmgr update` in the terminal to check for firmware updates.

Comment: Thank you, everything seems to be up-to-date...))