# My ubuntu partition runs at a hot temperature in my laptop (with Nvdia). How can I avoid it?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, overheating, temperature

I'm using my Ubuntu partition  as long as with my windows partition.

[image: temperatures in Ubuntu]

Ubuntu 20.04 lts & Windows 11
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz   1.99 GHz
NVIDIA GeForce MX150

Important note: For some reason in settings Ubuntu mentions another graphic card.

Maybe the answer relies here.
Should I try to Mesa Intel graphics driver and install Nvidia or it's too dangerous?

Many thanks in advance, god bless you all.

[image: Ubuntu settings screenshot]

Comment: Where are you getting that 60°C is hot? What is your basis of comparison?

Comment: I wouldn't consider 60s as high especially in a laptop ... You might, however, try a useful utility called [TLP](https://askubuntu.com/a/1309400) as it helps with overheating CPU/GPU